# is spark streaming state synchronized across partitions

Tags: spark-streaming

mapWithState updates the state for each key that is received. How would this work when executors are running in parallel? Is there a single state for a key or there is a state for each partition in Dstream rdd?

Answer (score 0):

Before updatkeByKey, spark shuffles the records using hash partition, so the records always end up in the same partition.